# paperclip default url not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In **user.rb** model `default_url` is set as:

```
default_url: lambda { |avatar| avatar.instance.set_default_url}

def set_default_url
  ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('male_user.png')
end

def avatar_urls
  return nil if self.avatar.blank?
    {
      original: self.avatar.url,
      medium: self.avatar.url(:medium),
      small: self.avatar.url(:small),
      thumbnail: self.avatar.url(:thumbnail),
    }
end
```

The path of image is: `app/assets/images`

If I run the same in console I get:

```
2.4.0 :030 > ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('male_user.png')
 => "/assets/male_user-dcd9e7de8ab7ccce17ef1322923cd4c46fcf5c7b3350f460b4fc403777c5685a.png"
```

If I don't upload any image, I get `null` as default url.
Whats wrong here? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Remove return nil if self.avatar.blank?

Comment: Still not working